# Laravel collection - flatten is not working

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have student database in which I have only 3 columns (id, name, dob). I've written simple select query,

```
return DB::table('student')->get(['id','name','dob']);
```

I'm getting response,

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Kaylah Hayes","dob":"1993-02-24"},{"id":2,"name":"Janis Casper Sr.","dob":"1994-07-11"}]
```

But I only need values like this,

```
[{1,"Kaylah Hayes","1993-02-24"}, {2,"Janis Casper Sr.","1994-07-11"}]
```

I tried using flatten method,

```
return DB::table('student')->get(['id','name','dob'])->flatten();
```

but it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
DB::table('student')->get(['id', 'name', 'dob'])->map(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->values();
});
```

Hope this helps!